# Maximizing zathura window, scrambled display

Tags: zathura

With zathura 0.4, I get a scrambled display when I maximize the window; it then looks like this (zooms the *content* of the page, but doesn't adjust page borders. It also freezes navigation):

[image: zathura display problem]]

This happens regardless of the file format of the document. I use Fluxbox as window manager.

On the positive side, it does not happen when I open the same document the second time (i.e. the document has an entry in `~/.local/share/zathura/history`).

Still it is an extremely annoying situation. I haven't found it mentioned as a bug anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug which has now been fixed with zathura 0.4.1.

**UPDATE:** …… and a regression with zathura 0.4.3.; exact bug again.

Comment: Having the same problem on current debian. Do you remember if there is a bug report for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with using mupdf as the backend; changing it to poppler solved it.